# Why doesn't XPath namespace-uri() work out of the box with Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to use the `namespace-uri()` function in XPath to retrieve nodes based on their fully qualified name. The query `//*[local-name() = 'customerName' and namespace-uri() = 'http://example.com/officeN']` in [this online XPath tester](http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx), among others, correctly returns the relevant nodes. Yet the following self-contained Java class does not retrieve anything. What am I doing wrong with `namespace-uri()`?

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

        XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(
                "//*[local-name() = 'customerName' and namespace-uri() = 'http://example.com/officeN']");
        String xml=
            "<Agents xmlns:n=\"http://example.com/officeN\">\n"+
            "\t<n:Agent>\n\t\t<n:customerName>Joe Shmo</n:customerName>\n\t</n:Agent>\n"+
            "\t<n:Agent>\n\t\t<n:customerName>Mary Brown</n:customerName>\n\t</n:Agent>\n</Agents>";
        System.out.println(xml);
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.err.println("\n\nNodes:");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.err.println(nodes.item(i));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this post!  It really helps for using namespace-uri for XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query looks fine. You also need to declare your DocumentBuilderFactory to be "namespace-aware".

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```